# Pointing sub-domain on Google domains to Wordpress running on Digital Ocean?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, a-record, digital-ocean, google-domains

I want a sub-domain on my google domains to point to `blog.mydomain.example`. Currently, it points to DNS at the root domain to Github pages. I want that to remain the same, but the blog subdomain to point to my wordpress running on digital ocean.

How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't Google Domains have some kind of web interface for making changes?

Comment: I'm just wondering how to do it. It's not clear to me.

Comment: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350

Comment: You just need to create an A record in DNS that points at the other server's IP.

Comment: And don't forget the AAAA record!

Answer (score 0):

You can map your Google subdomain in Google [Domains](https://domains.google.com/registrar?hl=en&_ga=2.185337005.568957508.1532114570-2134616700.1532114570), use either of the options described in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6346343?hl=en). Ensure to change the name servers to match that of [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars).

```
 1. ns1.digitalocean.com
 2. ns2.digitalocean.com
 3. ns3.digitalocean.com
```

Comment: This will change more than just the subdomain.

Comment: In the above documents, this is explained. Also note that for DNS changes to take effect, it might take a propagation period of several minutes, depending on your location, or 24-48 hours across the entire internet.